# Display issue in QPrinter Report

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

i am using QPrinter to create report and embed in the qt application. there is no issue in creating report, but display is the issue.

when i am scrolling the report  the display problem is coming. please have look at the Image.

[image: reports]

see the Notes Text.if i press CTRL and scroll then this is not coming. how to fix this.

Comment: i don't know. i try to edit the post after i am getting this down vote.

Comment: @cmannett85: one could say because it does not comply with the SO stack overflow guideline about showing what code he tries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution.

actually i used semi transparent color for the text.

```
painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(40,40,40,200),3,Qt::SolidLine));
```

after i removed and change into solid color, it's fixed

```
painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(140,140,140,255),3,Qt::SolidLine));
```

Thanks...